# QMessageBox::Ok is not responding for mouse clicks on Ok button

Tags: qt, mouseclick-event, qmessagebox

I am relatively new to `Qt`. I have the following piece of code in a function (which is in a user defined class inherited from `QObject`):

```
QMessageBox msgBox;

msgBox.setText("Try clicking Ok button.");   
int ret = msgBox.exec();

qDebug() << "Return Val:" << ret;

switch (ret)
{
    case QMessageBox::Ok:
    {
        qDebug()<<"Ok button clicked";
        break;
    }

    default:
    {
        qDebug()<<"Control Should Not Reach this log";
        break;
    }
}
```

After running this code, **`QMessageBox` with `Ok` Button pops up**. I am not able to click on **`Ok` button** using mouse, although using keyboard keys I can do that. No matter I use keyboard or use **button `Close`** (using either keyboard or mouse). I am always getting **return value `1024`** which is nothing but `QMessageBox::Ok`. That's why in the log always "*Ok button clicked*" is coming.

1. Why am I getting only `1024` **as return value**?
2. Is there something preventing mouse click on `QMessageBox` of **`Ok`
   button**?

Answer (score 1):

The docs (for Qt4) say

```
QMessageBox::QMessageBox ( QWidget * parent = 0 )

Constructs a message box with no text and no buttons.
```

Even if they are shown the buttons are probably out of order here. Try another constructor, use `setStandardButtons()`, or **use one of the static methods** like `QMessageBox::information()`, which in most cases is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. When declaring `msgBox`, no `parent` was given. Once I gave the parent it started working fine. Although I am not sure how that is impacting only the `Ok` button but not `close` button. 
Thanks.